# Cannot scroll when binding text/form in Ionic 3.9.2 on IOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a tabbar application, and have Account view on my last tab:

account.html:

```
<h2 ion-text text-center color="light" class="all-text" id="name" {{staticMember?.name}}</h2>

<ion-item [ngClass]="{'lp-invalid-input': account.get('name').invalid && (account.get('name').dirty || account.get('name').touched)}">
    <ion-input [formControl]="account.controls['name']" type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

... Couple of more <ion-item>
```

account.ts:

```
constructor(...) {
        this.account = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
            msisdn: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            password: new FormControl(this.TEMP_PASSWORD),
            confirmPassword: new FormControl(this.TEMP_PASSWORD)
        });
}

ionViewDidEnter(){
        this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
        let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Please wait...'
        });

        loading.present();

        this.http.get(Properties.API_URL + Properties.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT).toPromise()
        .then((res) => {
            this.staticMember = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.body));
            this.account.patchValue(res.body);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            loading.dismiss();
        });
}
```

When I click on it the first time, I cannot scroll . However, when I change tab and re-visit it, I start to be able to scroll.

When I visit the view the first time, when I cannot scroll, if I click on an  and focus on it, I can again scroll.

This only happens on an iOS device. Works as expected on Android and even on iOS Simulator. What am I missing?

Comment: I think there are some errors in console if yes can you please post it here

Comment: There are no errors. What's interesting is that it doesn't happen on Simulator, or Android, only on iOS.

Comment: Unitl you are assign staticMember value from api name properly is undefined in html

Comment: Can you please try this {{staticMember?.name}}

Comment: If this doesnt work only on iOS then I think you should mention this in question for quick debugging.

Comment: @AbuTaha Just figured that out, updated the question.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral have you tried ?. as I say and can you please try remove no-bounce?

Comment: I've tried removing `no-bounce` to no luck. I have a couple of other pages that I scroll with `no-bounce`. `?` also doesn't help.

Comment: @PareshGami I have updated the question significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug. `npm i ionic-angular@nightly` resolved the issue. References:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/1005
- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/1065